# Exporting R plots to eps - Not rendering in Latex

Tags: r, latex, eps

I am facing problems while trying to export R plots, When i googled, i found a solution :

```
postscript(file="result.eps", onefile=FALSE, horizontal=FALSE)
```

The eps image displays properly when viewed with image viewers.

The image need to be included in pdf reports, which i am preparing with Latex. The problem is , the plots are not displayed as expected in pdf prepared from Latex. Few things are missing (the axis ticks, axis labels, and text of legends). 
I just want to mention for completion - I created plots by appending plots on top of other plots with par(new=T).

Comment: once the ps is out, and you can view correctly with ghostscript or whatever, you can be sure the "problem" is not in how you create the ps from R. So we should investigate how you include it as graphics in your LaTeX doc. In case, it would become a problem for TeX exchange rather than SO.

Comment: I didn't find a really nice way to produce good eps-graphs with R... Especially if you want your plot to include special characters. I always use the tikzDevice package. It produces LaTeX-code which can be easily included in your file or processed standalone. The eps-graph is produced then by LaTeX. Even though it sounds a bit complex at the beginning there are advantages. For example, as LaTeX actually produces the plot, LaTeX fonts are used which gives your final document a consistent layout. Or you can use the formula settings of LaTeX within your graphs...

Comment: Try prefacing your `postscript()` line with a line of just: `setEPS()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command on Linux shell, where plot.eps is your eps file:

```
ps2eps -l -B -s b0 -c -n -f plot.eps
```

It will convert to plot.eps.eps, but it will be displayed properly. Had same issue, but this solved the problem.

You should have ps2eps if you have texmaker installed (I have also lynx installed).

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
sudo apt-get install lynx
```